# Parallelize a depth-first algorithm in python

Tags: python, multithreading, dataframe, tree, multiprocess

I need to create a connected graph from two dataframes called nodes and edges.

I am using https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-implement-depth-first-search-in-python algorithm to filter out the nodes, which are not connected.

Here is the code:

```
# Using a Python dictionary to act as an adjacency list
graph = {
    'A' : ['B','C'],
    'B' : ['D', 'E'],
    'C' : ['F'],
    'D' : [],
    'E' : ['F'],
    'F' : []
}

visited = set() # Set to keep track of visited nodes.

def dfs(visited, graph, node):
    if node not in visited:
        print (node)
        visited.add(node)
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            dfs(visited, graph, neighbour)

# Driver Code
dfs(visited, graph, 'A')
```

So first, I create the graph dictionary from my dataframes, and then use `dfs()` function to choose the connected nodes.

However this process, is a little bit time consuming. For a decent size nodes, edges dataframe it takes 157 seconds to execute. I would like to beat that via multiprocessing.

Is it possible to multiprocess this `dfs` function? If yes how?

**NOTE:** I am guessing, creating the graph dictionary is not the bottleneck here. However, here is also its code:

```
graph = dict.fromkeys(nodes['id'])

for key in graph.keys():
    t = []
    for i in edges.index:
        if key in edges['node_id'][i]:
            if edges['node_id'][i].index(key) == 0:
                index = 1
            else:
                index = 0

            t.append(edges['node_id'][i][index])
    graph[key] = list(set(t))
```

Comment: I dont think you can multiprocess dfs. But you can multiprocess a bfs search, Giving each child to seperate processes. But the isvisited matrix must be thread safe.

Comment: could you create a script with the easy example graph I gave on top @AlbinPaul ?

Comment: Writing a parallel dfs is not easy because of the nodes should be computed once, which means the threads should communicate/share a lot of information. Moreover, performing a load balancing is critical to get relatively good performances. The two points are very hard to do efficiently with the multiprocessing package in Python, and the threading package should be used here because the CPython GIL will prevent any speed-up. AFAIK, Cython and Numba could help for the first point, but not the second one, as they only provide a fork-join parallel model... Python is not great for such a computation

Comment: @JérômeRichard but cant I process the graph route `A->B->...` and `A->C->...` individually while adding the found nodes on a global set? Therefore I make the graph shorter, so faster?

Comment: The problem lies in "adding the found node on a global set". AFAIK, you cannot do that efficiently with the multiprocessing package because you need shared memory between multiple processes to solve this efficiently and certainly atomic operations to avoid race conditions (using lock will be inefficient) that I think cannot be done with this package. Moreover, note that sharing data between processes during the computation is already not so easy.

Comment: So basically adding into the same set with different processes is the problem here? if yes than what is the solution for this case? @JérômeRichard

Comment: Partially because this is not the only problem (see before). You can try using Cython/Numba, but I advise you to implement that in a native language with an advanced support of parallel programming (eg. C/C++ with OpenMP for example). Note that you may need to change the input data structure for sake of performance (still due to the GIL).

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I get at the moment with `multiprocessing`. So the idea is, since we know `'A'` is the root of the tree, `'B'` and `'C'` path could processed parallel.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool


def dfs(visited, graph, node):
    if node not in visited:
        visited.add(node)
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            dfs(visited, graph, neighbour)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    visited = set()
    graph = {
        'A': ['B', 'C'],
        'B': ['D', 'E'],
        'C': ['F'],
        'D': [],
        'E': ['F'],
        'F': []
    }

    a = [visited, visited]
    b = [graph, graph]
    c = ['B', 'C']

    pool = ThreadPool(2)
    pool.starmap(dfs, zip(a, b, c))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(visited)
```

Since we already know `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'` are connected, we can add those to the set in the end as well.

Finally in an ideal world, the paths of the network would be really seperated from each other so that, we could use `multiprocessing` efficiently...